# What are the punishments for leaving/dodging League of Legends games?

Tags: league-of-legends

My question is about dodging and leaving games and their punishments. I need to know if there is a specific chart that tells me how many times I can dodge/leave games without being punished, and if I do get punished what is the punishment?

Comment: The basics are thus: You got a free dodge every day. -3 LP and just 5 minute cooldown. After that you start got get slapped with things that are more severe. And just don't AFK in your games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, "dodging" and leaving a game are two different acts. "Dodging" is short for "queue dodging" and involves closing the client while in champion select. Leaving the game involves either closing the game, or being completely inactive for a sizable amount of time, while in an active match.

##### Dodging

When you "queue dodge," you impose a queue time penalty upon yourself. This penalty is enacted if you try to queue up again within 24 hours, and you'll have to wait the corresponding amount of time in order to actually enter the queue. Each dodge within a 24 hour window following the initial dodge stacks up this penalty into three total tiers. In ranked, this also comes with a loss of LP.

The related penalties for queue dodging within a 24 hour window are as follows, taken from the [community-curated wiki on Queue dodging](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Queue_dodging):

| **Queue Type** | **First Dodge** | **Second Dodge** | **Third Dodge** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Normal, Co-Op vs AI, Featured Game Modes | 6 minutes | 30 minutes | 720 minutes |
| ARAM | 15 minutes | 30 minutes | 720 minutes |
| Ranked | 6 minutes, - 3LP | 30 minutes, -10LP | 720 minutes, -10LP |

These penalties decrease by one tier every 12 hours.

In summary, unless you're playing ranked, it is typically okay to dodge once or twice a day if you feel like it.

##### Ready-check failure

There are also punishments (albeit light) for repeatedly missing the ready-check stage when your current queue has found a match for you. Repeatedly missing or declining ready checks will result in a 6 minute queue time penalty, and if you are queueing for ranked, a loss of 3 LP. Subsequent ready-check failures will result in various increased queue time penalties as well as a maximum of 10 LP loss if queueing for ranked.

##### LeaverBuster penalties

When you leave a game for an extended period of time via disconnection (voluntary or involuntary) or you leave the keyboard for an extended period of time, you are marked as a "leaver" and LeaverBuster kicks in. The first time you are marked as a "leaver" in a match, you will receive an alert prompt that looks like the following:

[image: Image of a LeaverBuster warning, indicating that leaving games is detrimental to your teammates with a textbox that requires the user to type "I agree" to continue.]

This is considered "Tier 0" of LeaverBuster's ramping penalty system. Continuing to leave games early or go AFK will increase the penalties. Here is a quick table of the LeaverBuster penalties, taken from the [community-curated wiki on LeaverBuster](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/LeaverBuster):

| **Tier** | **Penalty** | **Duration** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tier 0 | Warning | One time |
| Tier 1 | 5 minute queue delay | 5 games |
| Tier 2 | 10 minute queue delay | 5 games |
| Tier 3 | 15 minute queue delay | 5 games |
| Tier 4 | 24 hour queue lockout, then adds Tier 3's penalty | 1 game |
| Tier 5 | 3 day queue lockout, then adds Tier 3's penalty | 1 game |
| Tier 6 | 7 day queue lockout, then adds Tier 3's penalty | 1 game |
| Tier 7 | 2 week queue lockout, then adds Tier 3's penalty | 1 game |

Leaving a ranked game imposes an automatic loss onto your match history, regardless of whether your team is able to win without you or not. This tier system also seems to ramp more quickly when leaving ranked games, though the exact level of ramp is not documented.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can find all info regarding queue dodging [here](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Queue_dodging#:%7E:text=A%20League%20Points%20penalty%20is%20applied%20to%20the,negative%20numbers.%20This%20is%20capped%20at%20-100%20LP.).

If you are referring to the famous LeaverBuster then you can find a chart with all the information you are looking for [here](https://support-leagueoflegends.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201752714-LeaverBuster-FAQ#:%7E:text=If%20LeaverBuster%20determines%20you%20have%20been%20leaving%20matches,on%20the%20frequency%20and%20severity%20of%20the%20infractions.).

Comment: You should try and list/summarize the links in your answer in case those links become dead one day.  That way the information is preserved.  As it stands, this is essentially a link-only answer.